# After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path '[0] Issue

Tags: json, deserialization, filepath, backslash

I've been taking an error while deserialize json from file path.

My json model that comes from Model is (Model.GroupsJson) so:

```html
[{\"GroupContent\":\"<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://localhost:56502/images/uploads/1471441332_flat-style-circle-add.png\" style=\"height:32px; width:32px\" /></p>\n\",\"Questions\":[{\"QuestionId\":\"57c3de87b6455e070800df0d\",\"Order\":\"0\"},{\"QuestionId\":\"57c91f85b6455e13b0646e7d\",\"Order\":\"0\"},{\"QuestionId\":\"57c8317ab6455e08b47ad839\",\"Order\":\"0\"}]},{\"GroupContent\":\"<p>aaaa</p>\n\",\"Questions\":[{\"QuestionId\":\"57c7d4bfb6455e1a08f17a3a\",\"Order\":\"1\"},{\"QuestionId\":\"57c3d753b6455e1840ccf8b5\",\"Order\":\"1\"}]}]
```

and after i try to deserialize json model :

```
List<GroupModel> groupList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GroupModel>>(model.GroupsJSON)
```

And then this exception throws:

**Additional information: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path '[0].GroupContent', line 1, position 31.**

What do I have to do? Should I encode backslash characters on model?

Comment: Why property names and values is backslashed? This is not JSON.

Comment: I know, but I want to learn how can i serialize img element.